# Not updating in mongodb database based on id

Tags: mongodb, spring-mvc

Based on id I have to update a field in mongodb database.I am using spring-mvc,angularjs and mongodb. Id is comming to my spring class but its not updating. I am giving one sample of data which is in mongodb. From that data i have to update status field.

```
//mongodb

{   "_id" : ObjectId("556459bc4f3c9aac453f711d"),
    "name" : "TestTask3",
    "type" : null,
    "status" : "Pending Approval",
    "detail" : "TEst",
    "comments" : "TEst"
}

//Spring class
public void approveTask(String id){


        try {
            DBCollection collection = mongoTemplate.getCollection(RelmanUtil.MONGO_DB_COLL_TASKS);
            BasicDBObject query = new BasicDBObject("_id",id);        
            BasicDBObject update = new BasicDBObject();       
            update.put("$set", new BasicDBObject("status", "Assigned"));
            collection.update(query, update);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

You missed thing that you passed `id` as string to `mongo ObjectId` [check this](http://api.mongodb.org/java/2.6.5/org/bson/types/ObjectId.html) you should changed your code as below :

```
import org.bson.types.ObjectId;
public void approveTask(String id) {
  try {
    DBCollection collection = mongoTemplate.getCollection(RelmanUtil.MONGO_DB_COLL_TASKS);
    BasicDBObject query = new BasicDBObject("_id", ObjectId(id));
    //OR BasicDBObject query = new BasicDBObject("_id", new ObjectId(id));
    BasicDBObject update = new BasicDBObject();
    update.put("$set", new BasicDBObject("status", "Assigned"));
    collection.update(query, update);
  } catch(Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
  }
}
```

put `id` in `ObjectId(id) or new ObjectId(id)`